# Oracle insert too many values

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados

Pessoal Boa noite quero inserir dados em uma tabela mais apresenta um erro "too many values" colocarei meu codigo para vocês analisarem.

Insert into tab_Conta(id_correntista,id_banco, id_conta,id_agencia,nr_digito_conta,cd_tipo_correntista,vl_saldo) values(1,1,1,1,'123',1,'casa',10.00);

Minhas informações sobre a tabela tab_Conta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você estava passando mais valores para inserir do que colunas declaradas para receber.

Tente executar o insert abaixo:

```
insert into  tab_Conta (id_correntista,id_banco,id_conta,id_agencia,nr_digito_conta,cd_tipo_correntista,vl_saldo)values(1,1,1,1,123,1,10.00);
```

Comment: Foi man rodou.Obrigado, man outra dúvida ao tentar executar um insert com TO_Date ele apresenta o seguinte erro. foi localizado um caracter não-númerico onde se esperava um numerico. Comando insert tab_correntista(id_correntista,nm_nome,ds_sexo,nr_numero,id_municipio,id_cep,dt_nascimento) values(1,'Lucas','F',1,1,'12',TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));

Answer (score 0):

Foi man rodou.Obrigado, man outra dúvida ao tentar executar um insert com TO_Date ele apresenta o seguinte erro. foi localizado um caracter não-númerico onde se esperava um numerico. Meu Comando Oracle

insert tab_correntista(id_correntista,nm_nome,ds_sexo,nr_numero,id_municipio,id_cep,dt_nascimento) values(1,'Lucas','F',1,1,'12',TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));

Minha tabela correntista

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Man a coluna NM_NOME está do tipo DATE e você está passando uma string, altere o tipo da coluna para VARCHAR2, código abaixo:

    ALTER TABLE tab_correntista MODIFY (NM_NOME VARCHAR2(30));

Tente passar os valores com os tipos corretos das colunas
e execute o seu insert.